# Connectivity rule regarding two-level intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

in the sDNA documentation here: https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v4_0_1/network_preparation.html
is written that the network needs to be in shape as shown in Figure 5. Also at the bottom is written:

> Summary: ensure you understand spatial network connectivity rules, and
>   (for sDNA) that your network uses coincident endpoint connectivity.

Now comes my problem: I have a crossing exactly as shown in Figure 4, which has two different levels. One street A runs at elevation 0m from ground and runs under street B, which is at elevation 5m from ground. Street A is a usual road on the ground, while street B is a bridge running over street A, without having any possibility to get from street A to street B. 
When I want to prepare my network for the sDNA tool, I came across this problem and I am not sure how to solve it, since the documentation states I would need an intersection, while in reality there is no possibility to get from A to B or vice versa. I am a bit lost on how I should tackle this problem, since there is no way to change from A to B, while the documentation suggests I should add an intersection which is not available in real life.

(edited to correct manual url - manual 4.0.0 is deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add an intersection, just process the network as is: it's fine if you don't want the links to connect.

The manual says that coincident endpoint connectivity means *Lines are deemed to be connected if and only if they have coincident endpoints (the lines must end on exactly the same point).*

So, under a coincident endpoint connectivity rule, your two lines are not connected, which sounds like is just the way you want them.